# How to replace a matched regex expression with another string in C#

Tags: c#, .net, regex, string

I want to replace all instances of substrings that match a regular expression with another string in C#.  For example, the function call could look something like this:

```
inputString.Replace("foo*bar", "baz");
```

If the input string was (example only):

```
"foo2bar and foo2bax and fooTheQuickFax"
```

The output would be (example only):

```
"baz and foo2bax and fooTheQuickFax"
```

Does anyone know how to achieve this outcome?

Note: This question is NOT a duplicate.  This is asking about Regex specifically, featuring an example.  It is not asking about how to find the string between two strings - the person who marked this as duplicate did not read the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Regex.Replace("foo2bar and foo2bax and fooTheQuickFax", "foo.*bar", "baz");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Regex.Replace()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwewhkd1(v=vs.110).aspx) method like

```
  string pattern = "\\foo?bar";
  string replacement = "baz";
  Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern);
  string result = rgx.Replace(input, replacement);
```